# Is there an Authcache load event for fragments?

Tags: ajax, caching

I would like to create a callback javascript function to fire when one of my Authcache fragments is loaded via AJAX. Is there a way to hook into this event?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you register your JavaScript as a *behavior*, then it is executed whenever the DOM changes, also when a fragment was loaded by authcache (see [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722)). For example, the proper way to process any view - regardless of whether it is loaded via Authcache or not works something like this:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  "use strict";
  Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('.view', context).once(function () {
        var view = $(this);
        // do something with view.
      });
    }
  };
}(jQuery, Drupal));
```